# How to increase Firebase Authentication Session Time using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I developed an Agro App and I have enabled offline persistence because, after logging in, operators can spend 3-4 hours recording information offline until they return to the central point where there is internet.

The problem I have is that sometimes the application asks for credentials (login and password) again when they do not have internet, which means that they cannot record information offline or they have to go back to the central point to authenticate which is not efficient.

I understand that the Firebase auth token lasts up to an hour, how can I extend this time?

The way I am authenticating users using a provider is like following:

```
class UsuarioProvider {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;
  DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

  UsuarioProvider({FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth})
    : _firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ?? FirebaseAuth.instance;

 Future <Map<String, dynamic>> signIn(String email, String password) async {
   
   try {
      UserCredential result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User user = result.user;
      final token = await user.getIdToken();
      return {'ok' : true, 'token' : token, 'localId': user.uid, 'email' : user.email};
   } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      return {'ok': false, 'code': '${e.code}', 'mensaje': '${e.message}' }; 
   }
 }
```

How can I increase the Firebase Token Time? or How can I prevent users from being prompted for credentials when they are offline?

**UPDATE:**
The way I'm using to call firebase is:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  final prefs = new PreferenciasUsuario();
  await prefs.initPrefs();
  final pushNotificationsProvider = new PushNotificationsProvider(); 
  pushNotificationsProvider.initNotifications();
  FirebaseDatabase database;
  database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
  database.setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(10000000); // 10MB de cache
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication uses two types of tokens: a refresh token that "never" expires, and a short-lived ID token that is valid for an hour but is auto-refreshed by the SDK. There is no way to expand the life-time of the ID tokens.

If you want to pass a value along to a client that they can use for a longer period of time, you can mint an authentication cookie, which can be valid for up to two weeks. Note that this is a sensitive operation, so it can only be performed in trusted environments (typically by using the Firebase Admin SDK). For a full walkthrough of the process, see the Firebase documentation on [Managing Session Cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies).

Comment: Tks @puf. Two questions: 1. If the refresh token "never" expires, why my users are prompted to introduce their credentials again? 2. Can I implement Session Cookies using Cloud Functions?

Comment: You're not showing how you're calling Firebase. But since you're calling `user.getIdToken()`, that gives you an ID token. So if you use that, as said, it is only valid for an hour.

Comment: @puf. I updated the way I'm calling Firebase. What do I need to do in order to use "Refresh Tokens" instead "ID Tokens" ?

Comment: Calls to Firebase need an ID token. To exchange a refresh token for an ID token, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-refresh-token

Comment: But note that we're pretty deep into your application logic now, and I don't fully understand why the user needs to provide an ID token when they're offline.

Comment: Thanks @puf. If I understand you correctly, you suggest that I check at what points I am actually using the ID token and if I can avoid them I can remove the 'user.getIdToken()' and thus avoid asking the user for their credentials when offline. Am I getting it right?

Comment: None of the code you've added your question uses the ID token. Where are you using `final token = await user.getIdToken()`?

Comment: I just removed the uses of "token", then I removed `user.getIdToken()`. Nevertheless, I was able to identify that Android prompted for credentials when the App is minimized and offline more than 25 minutes. What could I do to fix it?

Comment: Did you also find where that call comes from? Because without knowing what causes the prompt, we can't do much. We've gone pretty far from your original "How to increase Firebase Authentication Session Time using Flutter?" question at this point.

Comment: Thanks @puf. I don't know what causes the prompt, but I found giant differences between IOS and Android (with the same Flutter Code). I will publish a new question with the test results.

Comment: Differences between IOS (long lived session) and Android (25 mins max) in... [How long does a Firebase Auth session last when the user is offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65397458/how-long-does-a-firebase-auth-session-last-when-the-user-is-offline)